# PhpStorm navigate to style in PUG

Tags: sass, phpstorm, pug

In my project I use PUG and SCSS.
When clicking a class name in PUG file I expect PhpStorm navigate me to appropriate style definition in a SCSS file.
For example, in code

```
p.text-white-75.mb-4
```

clicking to `text-white-75` I would like jump to

```
.text-white-75 {
}
```

fragment in styles.scss file.

But when I click it, PhpStorm shows message "Cannot find declaration to go to".

PUG plugin is installed, as far as SCSS. For both correct code style is shown in editor.

What should I set up additionally, to make navigation work?

Answer (score 3):

It's a known limitation of Pug support in the IDE; please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-29449 and linked tickets to be notified on any progress with this issue